# Rules governing the syntax of incorporating system query options in URL (OData)

Tags: rest, url, odata

I find that the syntax used to incorporate system query options in an URL mainly falls into two categories.

**1. Doesn't introduce a new segment.** Examples include `http://host/service/Products?$top=5`, and `http://host/service.svc/Employees?$filter=Region eq @p1&@p1='WA'`.

**2. Does introduce a new segment.** For example, `http://host/service/Cateoriges?$orderby=Products/$count`. Please mind the segment delimiter `/` before `$count`.

I'm wondering whether there is a simple rule that governs which syntax to use. Such a rule, it exists at all, could help provide insights, strengthen the understanding, and determine the correct syntax to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are spelled out in the [grammar for OData URIs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt). I wouldn't call them simple.

Consider using a client-side library that abstracts away the need to know anything about OData URI syntax.